# Store values from a Flask app to a Json file on Heroku for later invocations

Tags: flask, heroku

I have deployed a flask app on Heroku where I need to store a value in `config.json` for later invocations on different `@app.route`. My implementation is as below :

```
@app.route('/token',methods=['POST'])
def token():
    token_payload = json.loads(request.data)
    temp = {'token':token_payload['access_token']}
    with open('config.json') as json_file:
        config = json.load(json_file)
        config.update(temp)
    write_json(config,'config.json')
    return('Token Received')

with open('config.json') as json_file:
    config_data = json.load(json_file)

access_token = config_data['token']
```

However, even though I get successfull response "Token Received", the `access_token` is still referring to old value in `config_data['token']` in later invocations. But, this implementation is working on my local machine.

How do I make it work on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

A fundamental principle of Heroku's service model is that dynos, i.e. the virtualized machines that your code is running on, are ephemeral. Whenever a dyno gets restarted (which happens automatically at least once every 24h and on every new release you push to Heroku), you get a completely fresh image. This implies that anything you have written to disk before (or on a different dyno, if you are running more than one in parallel) will have disappeared.

Any persistent data you want to use has to be stored on a database or any other external service such as AWS S3.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for the reply. I only need to run this app for 6 hours a day. Assuming I could run the dyno without idling or restarting for 6 hours, is it possible to store the access_token into dyno's active memory for future invocations till it idles or get shutdown.

Comment: Well, the exact time when the restart happens is actually not predictable, because Heroku adds a random value of up to 216 minutes to the 24h, so it will eventually creep into your 6h window. As a general rule, Heroku is designed to store any persistent data outside of the dyno in an extra service such as a database. If you do not want to add any outside storage but want to persist data then Heroku is probably not the best option for you to host it.

Comment: Does openshift allow persistent data or is it exactly like Heroku?

Comment: I don't know anything about openshift.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot.